# Pentaho Report Designer error: Assert: Shift is not as expected

Tags: java, reporting, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I'm building a report which is basically a big set of pie charts (13 of them) grouped by user.

Each pie chart uses a diferent query (actually, same query, different table). I laid them down, and everything was fine until pie number 11. Pie number eleven crashed PRD with the error:

```
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.InvalidReportStateException: Assert: Shift is not as expected: realY=252100000 != expectation=251700000; Shift=63200000; AdditionalShift=-400000; RealShift=62800000
```

I checked the query and it is ok.

Anyone can explain what is happening, or give me a hint about what is failing?

Full stacktrace:

> org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.InvalidReportStateException:
>   Assert: Shift is not as expected: realY=252100000 !=
>   expectation=251700000; Shift=63200000; AdditionalShift=-400000;
>   RealShift=62800000
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.PaginationStepLib.assertBlockPosition(PaginationStepLib.java:162)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.PaginationStep.handleStartBlockLevelBox(PaginationStep.java:169)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.PaginationStep.startBlockLevelBox(PaginationStep.java:159)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:421)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:423)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:423)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processCanvasLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:370)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:55)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:423)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:423)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:423)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:423)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:423)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:51)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBoxChilds(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:440)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.PaginationStep.performPagebreak(PaginationStep.java:116)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableRenderer.performPagination(PageableRenderer.java:134)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.AbstractRenderer.processPage(AbstractRenderer.java:517)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processPaginationLevel(AbstractReportProcessor.java:968)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.prepareReportProcessing(AbstractReportProcessor.java:534)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.graphics.PrintReportProcessor.getNumberOfPages(PrintReportProcessor.java:78)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.PreviewPane$RepaginationRunnable.run(PreviewPane.java:271)
>           at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.util.Worker.run(Worker.java:174)

Comment: Please put the full stacktrace here, putting resources outside stackoverflow really dimishes the posibilities of someone answering your question.

Comment: I have run into this same error today.  My report has several data sets and I have added inline/banded sub reports throughout to account for multiple sources of data.  I believe this error in my case, and maybe yours, is produced due to the number of sub reports on the report.  I don't believe there to be a maximum amount allowed but when I remove some of the sub reports the report renders fine.  Unfortunately it's not an option to remove the sub reports so I'm also looking for a solution to this error.  If I find a solution I will re-post but I have been unsuccessful searching for an answer.

Comment: There is a Bug registered at Pentaho's JIRA. The developers want sample reports with this occurrence.

I wont be able to send them a proper anonymized example any time soon.

The link is: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-5034?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed as case http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-4841 . Grab the latest build from CI (either the [master/5.1 branch](http://ci.pentaho.com/view/Reporting/) or the [5.0-branch](http://ci.pentaho.com/view/x5.0x/) and your report will run fine.)